# Deserialisation error with SWXMLHash

Tags: swift, swxmlhash

I have the following XML structure (this is a stripped-down example):

```
<Root>
    <SomeData>Some value</SomeData>
    ...
    <ClientInfo>
        <Client>MD</Client>
        <Name>Massive Dynamic</Name>
    </ClientInfo>
</Root>
```

With the following model:

```
struct ClientInfo : XMLElementDeserializable {
    let Client : String
    let Name : String

    static func deserialize(_ node: XMLIndexer) throws -> ClientInfo {
        return try ClientInfo(
            Client: node["Client"].value(),
            Name: node["Name"].value()
        )
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to parse the XML as follows:

```
let clientInfo : ClientInfo? = try? xml.children[0]["ClientInfo"].value()
```

However, it keeps failing with an `ImplementationIsMissing` error as if my custom `deserialize` function doesn't exist.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just one small mistype... instead of `XMLElementDeserializable`, you should use `XMLIndexerDeserializable`.

The below works for me in a Playground:

```
import SWXMLHash

let xmlData = "<Root>" +
"<SomeData>Some value</SomeData>" +
"    <ClientInfo>" +
"       <Client>MD</Client>" +
"       <Name>Massive Dynamic</Name>" +
"   </ClientInfo>" +
"</Root>"

let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(xmlData)

struct ClientInfo : XMLIndexerDeserializable {
    let Client: String
    let Name: String

    static func deserialize(_ node: XMLIndexer) throws -> ClientInfo {
        return try ClientInfo(
            Client: node["Client"].value(),
            Name: node["Name"].value()
        )
    }
}

let info: ClientInfo? = try? xml.children[0]["ClientInfo"].value()
```

The distinction between those two gets a little confusing and it definitely needs to be improved in the library. The gist is that `XMLElementDeserializable` is for standalone types (e.g. strings, ints, dates, etc.) that don't have children nodes.